# Closing the navigation bar after scrolling to an anchor point

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently working on a one pager website that uses bootstrap, and in the navbar I have anchor points. Whenever I go to an anchor point in the mobile version the menu stays open and blocks the content. What can I do so that the menu closes after clicking a link/anchor point.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflooooooow.. I would like to let you know that you need to provide minimal code to answer your question  or a demo in fiddle too would be great.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap javascript function `$().dropdown('toggle')`

For more information see documentation [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)